# Graphql - call query in graphqlplayground from connected DB

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I'm just starting with graphql and having a few problems calling a basic query in the playground.

I have a server.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'variables.env' })

const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server')

//Monogoose schemas
const Recipe = require('./models/Recipe');

const { typeDefs } = require('./schema');
const { resolvers } = require('./resolvers')

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
})

// Connect to DB
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { autoIndex: false })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('DB connected')
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err))

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`server listening on ${url}`)
})
```

a schema.js

```
const gql = require('graphql-tag');

exports.typeDefs = gql`

  type Recipe{
    _id: ID
    name: String!
    category: String!
    description: String!
    instructions: String!
    createdDate: String
    likes: Int
    username: String
  }

  type Query {
    getAllRecipes: [Recipe]
  }

`
```

a resolvers.js

```
exports.resolvers = {

  Query: {
    getAllRecipes: async (root, args, { Recipe }) => {
      const allRecipes = await Recipe.find()
      return allRecipes
    }
  },
```

and a mongoose schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const RecipeSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  instructions: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  likes: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  username: {
    type: String
  }

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Recipe', RecipeSchema)
```

The server and connection to the DB work and when I open the playground the schema is shown. I have data in the DB

When I run query:

```
query{
  getAllRecipes{
    name
  }
}
```

I get an error `"Cannot read property 'find' of undefined",`

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `resolvers.js` file you're expecting `Recipe` to come from the `context` argument, but you did not add it anywhere from what I can tell from your snippets.

During the initialization of your ApolloServer instance, you can pass a `context` property that will be injected on all resolvers:

```js
...
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: {
    Recipe,
  },
});
```

The `context` property can also be a function that returns an object at the end, in case you want something more elaborated.

For more details on the option and also on others you can pass, see: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/.